# AMP with Universal Analytics

Tags: reactjs, tracking, universal-analytics

I cannot seem to get AMP pages working with Universal Analytics

I have a React application and within this we have some AMP pages that require page view tracking.

I followed the documentation(https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/amp?technology=tagmanager) in regards to setting this up with google tag manager.

1. Created the new container ID and published this to live.
2. Copied the script tag and inserted it into the head of the page
3. Then copied the amp-analytics tag and inserted that just after the body tag and replacing the ID with our container ID
4. Then created the tag and trigger in tag manager to enable the event to show upon landing on any AMP page.

However when trying to test this in preview mode the container ID cannot be found, I look in the network tab and it seems that the request is fine as I receive a 200 back. But preview mode indicates it cannot be found.

I am not sure what to do, am i missing something, can this be tested this way or is this an outdated way of achieving our desired result.